# Python Azure Function : I am trying to trigger the POST call from local host which is throwing the error as attached with 500

Tags: python, azure-functions, pyodbc

[image]

I have the python azure function [image]I am trying to trigger the POST call from local host | deployed using pipeline which is throwing the error as attached with 500 however if i deploy it using azure extention from vscode the function returns the response.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
            connection_string+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi')
        conn = connection.cursor()
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: An editable code could've helped replicate the issue. Alongside, you may want to validate your credentials & firewall settings.